# Android: hide EditText of another activity by clicking button running activity

Tags: android

I have two activity A and B. I want when I click button activityA, I hide EditText of activityB.
I used the code below but it gives me exception.

```
buttonA= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_actA);
        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(FileExplore.this, AllSettings.class);

           EditText editTextB= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_actB);
           editTextB.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

           startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

How can I do this ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `EditText` of `ActivityB` directly from `ActivityA`. What you can actually do is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FileExplore.this, AllSettings.class);                     
intent.putExtra("EditTextVisible", false);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in `ActivityB` in `onCreate()`:

```
if(!getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EditTextVisible")) {
    editTextB.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Please how can I declare "EditTextVisible" on activity A and B ?

Comment: You don't need to "declare". Just access it the way I have mentioned. You can use any other `String` in place of `"EditTextVisible"`. It's a Key-Value pair